# Fastify server doesn't update pages correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I'm working on an account system for a chat app I'm making, but the pages won't update. I can only get an updated page if I make an entirely new route for it. I'm using a serv00 server, and can't seem to find the issue. I'm restarting the server, and also saving the files, too. I've tried to clear cache, and multiple other things. Here's my app.js:

```js
// Imports
const pino = require('pino');
const pretty = require('pino-pretty');
const logger = pino(pretty());
const fastify = require("fastify")({ logger: logger });
const fastifyIO = require("fastify-socket.io");
const cors = require("@fastify/cors");
const striptags = require("striptags");
const ejs = require('ejs');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const fmsql = require('fastify-at-mysql');
const markdown = require("markdown-it")({
  html: true,
  linkify: true,
  typographer: true,
  breaks: true,
})
  .use(require("markdown-it-emoji"))
  .use(require("markdown-it-abbr"))
  .use(require("markdown-it-deflist"))
  .use(require("markdown-it-footnote"))
  .use(require("markdown-it-ins"))
  .use(require("markdown-it-sub"))
  .use(require("markdown-it-sup"))
  .use(require("markdown-it-mark"))
  .use(require("markdown-it-anchor"))
  .use(require('markdown-it-link-attributes'), {
  attrs: {
    target: '_blank',
  }
})
  .use(require("markdown-it-task-lists"));

// Declarations
/* none needed */
  
// Functions
function cleanseMessage(message) {
    return striptags(markdown.render(striptags(message)), [
            'strong',
            'i',
            'em',
            'code',
            'a',
            'div',
            'sub',
            'sup',
            's',
            'abbr',
            'dl',
            'hr',
            'ins',
            'section',
            'ol',
            'li',
            'sup',
            'sub',
            'code',
            'pre',
            'br',
            'h1',
            'h2',
            'h3','h4','h5','h6', 'ul', 'input'
          ])
}

function createMessage(username, message, bio) {
  let cleansedMessage = cleanseMessage(message);
  let formattedUsername = `<span class='pfplink' onclick='window.location = "/profile?user=${username}&bio=${bio}"'>${username}</span>`;
  let formattedDate = `<span style='font-size: small;'> [at <span id='date'></span>]</span>`;
  let formattedMessage = `<div id='message'><pre>${cleansedMessage}</pre></div>`;
  let formattedDiv = `<div style='margin: 10px 0;'><span>${formattedUsername}${formattedDate}</span>${formattedMessage}</div>`;

  return formattedDiv;
}

// Init
fastify.register(fastifyIO);
fastify.register(cors);
fastify.register(
  require('@fastify/compress'),
  { global: true }
);
fastify.register(require("@fastify/view"), {
  engine: {
    ejs: require("ejs"),
  },
});
fastify.register(require('@fastify/static'), {
  root: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
});

fastify.register(fmsql, {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
})
  
fastify.register(function (instance, options, done) {
  instance.setNotFoundHandler(function (req, res) {
                                                        code = 404
                                                        msg = "Can't find that webpage."
                                                        res.view("/views/error.ejs")
  })
  done()
}, { prefix: '/' })
                                                         
fastify.setErrorHandler(function (err, req, res) {
  request.log.warn(err)
  var statusCode = err.statusCode >= 400 ? err.statusCode : 500
  res
    .code(statusCode)
    .type('text/html')
    .send(ejs.render(fs.readFileSync('./views/error.ejs', 'utf8'), { code: statusCode, msg: err.message }))
})

// Routes                                                         
fastify.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.view("/views/main.ejs");
});

fastify.get("/chat", function (req, res) {
    res.view("/views/chat.ejs");
});

fastify.get("/profile", function (req, res) {
  user = req.query.user
  bio = req.query.bio

  res.view("/views/profile.ejs");
});

fastify.get("/edit", function (req, res) {
  res.view("/views/editinfo.ejs");
});

fastify.get("/about", function (req, res) {
  res.view("/views/about.ejs");
});

fastify.get("/rules", function (req, res) {
    res.view("/views/rules.ejs");
});

fastify.ready().then(() => {
  
fastify.io.on('connection', (client) => {
  logger.info('Client connected...')
  client.join('::GENERAL')

  client.on('join', function(data) {
    if (data.user.disName !== undefined) {
      if (data.preroom !== '') {
        client.leave(data.preroom);
        client.join(data.room);
        client.to(data.room).emit('broad', `<div class='statusmsg'>${data.user.disName}@${data.user.ugn} joined this chat room.</div>`);
        client.to(data.preroom).emit('broad', `<div class='statusmsg'>${data.user.disName}@${data.user.ugn} left this chat room.</div>`);
        client.emit('broad', `<div class='statusmsg'>You joined ${data.room}.</div>`);
      } else {
        logger.info(`${data.user.disName}@${data.user.ugn} joined.`);
        client.to('::GENERAL').emit('broad', `<div class='statusmsg'>${data.user.disName}@${data.user.ugn} joined this chat room.</div>`);
        client.emit('broad', "<div class='statusmsg'>You joined the chat room.</div>");
      }
    }
  });

  client.on('connect_error', (err) => {
    logger.error(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`)
  })

  client.on('messages', (data) => {
    if (data.user.disName !== undefined) {
      const message = createMessage(`${data.user.disName}@${data.user.ugn}`, data.message, data.user.bio);
      client.emit('broad', message);
      client.to(data.room).emit('notification', data);
      client.to(data.room).emit('broad', message);
    }
  });
})
});
                                                         
fastify.listen({ path: 'passenger', host: '127.0.0.1' });
```

Comment: FastifyIo plugin does not work with fastify 4. Use fastify-websocket

Comment: it says it does on the github page. (https://github.com/ducktors/fastify-socket.io?tab=readme-ov-file#fastify-socketio)